# $\lambda A$ is ideal then $A$ is ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need a hint to start this problem.

> let be $D$ a conmutative domain and $\lambda\in D\setminus\{0\}$ and $A$ a subgroup of $D$.

if $\lambda A$ is an ideal then $A$ is an ideal.

Comment: @Weaam I don't think that the problem is so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a subgroup all that remains to be shows is that $ca\in A$ for all $c\in D$, $a\in A$. From $\lambda a\in \lambda A$ we know that $c\lambda a\in\lambda A$, i.e., $c\lambda a=\lambda a'$ with $a'\in A$. Then $\lambda\cdot(ca-a')=0$ and as $\lambda \ne 0$ and $D$ is a domain we conclude $ca-a'=0$.

Comment: A hint was enough, but i was lost in this course so it helps a lot. Thanks